# Generator that produces sequence 0,1,2,3,

Tags: python, count, range, generator

Does Python provide a function that generates the endless sequence 0,1,2,3,... ?

It is easy to implement it:

```
def gen_range():
  count = 0
  while True:
    yield count
    count = count + 1
```

But I suppose, this exists already in Python.

Comment: You can get an iterator with [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. Check out the [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) built-in function. As you can read in the linked docs, you can set the starting number and also the step. Float numbers are also allowed.

Here's how you can use it:

```
from itertools import count

for n in count():
    print(n)
```

This is going to print 0, 1, 2, 3, ... (Be careful! This example won't stop until you force it to stop somehow).

Comment: @daniel-hao It would be great if OP explains what is his goal with getting an infinite generator

Comment: @Cardstdani that's not relevant, there are many use cases for that

Comment: I am going through a file line by line and I want to know the line numbers. Therefore my loop is `for line, line_number in zip(file.splitlines(), count()):`.